# Geometry Problem: In Triangle ABC, draw a perpendicular on line BC such that Area of ABXY is equal to Area of XYC

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles, geometric-construction

**Problem**

In any given Triangle ABC, construct a perpendicular XY upon line BC using only a compass and a straight edge such that Area of Quadrilateral ABYX is equal to Area of Triangle XYC.

**Diagram**

[See here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ULazc.png)

**What I've done so far**

Construct the median AM from apex A on line BC such that BM = MC.

Now, Area[ABM] = Area[ACM].

Suppose the line XY is drawn. Then let it cross the median at O. Therefore, 
by sine-area rule on Triangles AOX and MOY,
1/2 * AO * OX * angle[AOX] = 1/2 * MO * OY * angle[MOX]

=> AO * OX = MO * OY.

I'm stuck here. Can anybody please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's draw an altitude $AH$ on $BC$ and denote $b=BH$, $c=HC$, $h=AH$ and $y=YC$.
We can also see, that $x=XY=yh/c$ (from similarity of $\triangle XYC$ and $\triangle AHC$).

The area of $XYC$:
$$A_1=\frac{xy}2=\frac{y^2h}{2c}.$$

The area of $ABC$:
$$
A_2=\frac{h(b+c)}2.
$$

You want $A_1=A_2/2$, thus
$$y^2 = \frac{c(b+c)}2,\quad\text{or}\quad y=\sqrt{c\cdot\frac{b+c}2}$$

Can you try to construct the latter?

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was finally able to solve the problem. The last bit was easy...I just had to construct a square with equal area to rectangle with lengths c and (b+c)/2 then take its side! I was going about in  dead ends for two days over this.